# all.js - FB.getSession incompatible with OAuth2

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

I'm including the FaceBook JS SDK like this:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
```

But eventually I get this error in FireBug:

```
FB.getSession incompatible with OAuth2. http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js
```

I'm completely lost.  I've been trying to figure out what's going on since yesterday but no luck.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Get Session function is no longer used.  The FB.getAuthResponse method is a replacement for the FB.getSession method which was deprecated after the migration to OAuth 2.0.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getAuthResponse/

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the problem. I was working on a project while they were rolling out the changes to their platform so it really threw me for a loop ><

Answer (score 1):

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/oauth2-https-migration/ - you're probably going to need to revisit the Javascript and Authentication docs - the oauth migration which was mandatory by Oct 1st was switched on which will have broken non-compliant apps

Answer (score 0):

Try these modifications:

```
1) Upgrade to Facebook PHP SDK 3.1.1 (if you are using that)
2) Modify <fb:login-button> "perms" attribute to "data-scope"
Before:
<fb:login-button perms="email" on-login="my_function_login_complete(arguments)">
Facebook Logon
</fb:login-button>
After fix:
<fb:login-button data-scope="email" on-login="my_function_login_complete(arguments)">
Facebook Logon
</fb:login-button>
3) Replace JavaScript function call "FB.getSession" for "FB.getAuthResponse"
4) Alter JavaScript function parameter "response" in "FB.login()"
a) response.session => response.authResponse
b) response.session.access_token => response.authResponse.accessToken
Before:
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.session) {
    console.log("User is connected to the application.”);
    var accessToken = response.session.access_token;
  }
});
After fix:
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
    console.log("User is connected to the application.”);
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  }
});
5) Alter JavaScript function parameter "response" in "FB.getLoginStatus()"
a) response.session.user_id => response.authResponse.userID
b) response.session.access_token => response.authResponse.accessToken
Before:
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    var uid = response.session.user_id;
    var accessToken = response.session.access_token;
...
After fix:
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
...
```

More details here:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/503
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525

Good luck! :)